# Bulk Edit for annotation set in alexa ASR not working

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am interested in using the annotation set feature that is part of model evaluation in the Alexa developer console. Currently, I am able to import in the zip file containing all the mp3 files, however the "Expected Transcription" for each mp3 file is not filled in. According to https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/asr/create-annotation-set.html#metadata, I can use the bulk edit feature to fill in each file's metadata at once instead of doing it one at a time. However, when I try to import the bulk edit file (I have tried both CSV and JSON) the mp3 file does not get the "Expected Transcription" line filled in. Instead a new annotation is created where the mp3 file is then missing. I have included a picture below for better reference. I have tried uploading the bulk edit first and then the mp3 files but that does not give me better results.

What the annotation set on ASR in developer console looks like: [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is one that would have to be reproduced to be diagnosed. Can you share a few sample entries from your JSON, some repro steps?

Comment: Yes, the post has been edited to reflect this

Comment: Do you want to see more sample entries, right now it is just one

Comment: @LetMyPeopleCode let me know if you need anything else. One thing to note, in the website listed above it is written upload "annotation set of audio files to an AWS S3 bucket", would uploading the mp3 to the annotation console be considered doing this?

Comment: By any chance did you figure out the solution for this? I'm having the same problem. I have also tried to upload a zip file with mp3. I then looked up `uploadId` for every file. Then I created CSV (and JSON) annotation file with that appropriate `uploadId`. Yet, I'm having the same issue. A new annotation is created without an audio file.

Comment: Hey Jiri, I was unable to figure this out so I ended up using the API. If you figure it out, please let me know!